# If $f\circ g = g\circ f$ then $f = g$?

Tags: inverse, inverse-function

Is it true or there's an error in my understanding?

$$f\circ g = g\circ f \iff f=g?$$

Comment: We can't see your reasoning, so hard to know where exactly you got this. But it is not true (take two functions that are inverses, for example).

Comment: @MorganRodgers There are some very good answers, so I think the question was clear enough for some people.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any pair of (integer) power functions have this property.
$$(x^n)^m =(x^m)^n$$

Comment: Downvotes should be explained. The one user who downvoted all three answers I mean.

Comment: I agree.  Nothing is wrong with either answer and both are right on point with the question.  It's almost as if the downvoter were wishing to make the claim true but in mathematics, wishes go nowhere.

Comment: I agree with you guys. I even checked my answer and yours... But as @OscarLanzi says, both are correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot @DavidPeterson! Your answer was very revealing!

Answer (score 4):

Well:

$$f(x) = x, g(x) = x^2$$

Then

$$f(g) = x^2 = g(f)$$

Therefore, it is not true.

Comment: You don't understand what "proof by contradiction" means.

Comment: What a confusion....Thanks

Comment: It's not "proof by counterexample," either. A counterexample *disproves* the claim.

Comment: Sorry, what it is then?

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr. N! It's clear now!

Comment: You're welcome, @Leandro!

Comment: @Mr.N Thank you very much for your help...with lot of my heart.

Comment: @Sebastiano You're welcome, but how exactly did I help you?

Comment: @Mr.N I have again before give to you my "grazie assai" for your answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3801135/test-for-a-continuous-function. I'm sorry for your downvotes.

Comment: @Sebastiano you're welcome. No problems