# Test for a continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

Let $f$ be a function defined in $[0, 6]$, continuous in $[0, 6]$
and it is provided of a third derivative in $]0, 6[.$ Which of the following assertions is **false**?

$$\fbox{A}\quad f \text{ has no asymptotes; }$$
$$\fbox{B}\quad f \text{ may have no critical points; }$$
$$\fbox{C}\quad f \text{ has a relative maximum or has a minimum
relative; }$$
$$\fbox{D}\quad f'' \text{ is continuous in } ]0; 6[;$$
$$\fbox{E}\quad \text{If } f'(5) = f''(5) = 0 \text{ and } f'''(5) = 7, \text{then } f \text{ has an inflection point with 
a horizontal tangent at } x = 5$$

### Below there is the original question in Italian Language. Above there is the translation.

[image: I]

---

My attempt of resolution for to find the correct answer. The $\fbox{A}$ is true being $f$ is continuous in $[0,6]$.  The $\fbox{B}$ is true for the Weierstrass' theorem: remark that $[0,6]$ is closed set. If I think to the polynomial $\deg(p(x))=6$ and $\fbox{C}$ for me it is true. For the $\fbox{D}$ I have thought that if $f$ and it is provided of a third derivative in $]0,6[$, almost for $f''$ is continuous in $]0,6[$. I'd say the $\fbox{E}$ is **false**, but I can't justify it.

I ask if my reasoning is correct or there are incongruities.

Comment: I'm sorry but your explanation for $C$ is that "for me it's true". Maybe you would like to be a little more precise. Also check again for any mispell and typos; for example in $E$ $f''(5)$ is equal to both $0$ and $7$.

Comment: @alphaomega Hi, I have put the original question in Italian language. But it is important that you see the values. I have written that $C$ it is true and no false.

Comment: @downvoter: Why is there a downvoted? What is the reason? There is a closure for **Needs details or clarity**: what are the details? I have put the original question and I have translate it.

Comment: Why downvoting a question that shows work ? What is wrong with people ?

Comment: @jimjim I'm agree totally with you. What must I add?

Comment: @Sebastiano : You have added enough, I saw this at -1, I see many crap questions with no work and showing no initiative that are at +2 , so I couldn't understand why there is -1 for this question.

Comment: @jimjim There are now two request of **Needs details or clarity**. :-) The world is beautiful because it is varied, that is, made by people of different natures. Someone is joking. I put a lot of effort into it but obviously this is not necessary.

Comment: @downvoters: Could someone please explain to me the reason for the closure and the negative evaluation of my question? Thank you.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this question is for me quite clear: the O.P. wants to know whether his answer to a test is correct or not. I don't understand why it was closed. Anyway, I would say it is C which is false (if you consider an extremum as being attained in the interior of the interval).

Comment: @Bernard Speaking only for myself, I voted to close because all five answers appeared to be true, and also because I doubted that the original translation of "flesso a tangente orizzontale" as "horizontal tangent line" was correct. You amended the latter to "inflection point with a horizontal tangent", and Google translate agrees with you, so re-opening is probably justified. However, even with the updated translation, all five appear true to me. The extreme value theorem says nothing about extrema needing to occur in the interior, and is false with that definition.

Comment: So, I still think the question is ill posed.

Comment: @Bungo: I don't think that, once amended, it is ill-posed; and I had a sketch for an answer (I think it's C which is false).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, C is false if you understand as a relative extremum (or local extremum) an extremum on a neighbourhood of a point in the *interior* of $[0,6]$. Indeed , here is a counterexample satisfying all the hypotheses, which has neither a local maximum nor a local minimum on $[0,6]$, albeit it has a maximum and a minimum:
$$f(x)=\frac 76(x-5)^3.$$

On the other hand, E is true, because if $f'''(5)=7$, it is positive in a small neighbourhood of $5$, say $I=(5-ε, 5+ε)$ (derivatives satisfy the  intermediate value property), so that $f''$ is increasing on this interval. Therefore , if $f''(5)=0$, we have $f''(x)<0$ on $(5-ε,5)$ and $f''(x)>0$ on $(5, 5+ε)$, so that $f'$ has a local  minimum on $I$, which corresponds to the definition of an inflection point.

Comment: Thank you very much for your precious help.....thank you with all my heart.

Comment: I continue to not understand the downvotes. Boh.

Comment: But what about the "horizontal tangent"? I thought it had to had a horizontal tangent at $x=5$, which is false. It's a parabola.

Comment: It does have a horizontal tangent since $f'(5)=0$. And it isn't a parabola since it has a cubic equation.

Answer (score -1):

Let's eliminate one by one.

**A** If $f$ is continuous in $[0,6]$ it means it is bounded for every $x \in [0,6]$. Therefore, no asymptotes. Thus, it's true.

**B** That is also true. For instance: $f(x) = e^x$. Remember that, in order to find critical points, we must take the first derivative and test for each $x$ that $f'=0$ or does not exist.

**C** That's also true. In order to find (local) maxima and minima we must consider both critical points and the bounds of the interval.

**D** Well, if $f'''$ is continuous in $]0,6[$ it means that $f''$ is differentiable in the same interval. Therefore, continuous as well.

**E** This is the false one. We may not ensure that the tangent will be horizontal. It would be correct if it said: ...$f'$ has a horizontal tangent at $x = 5$

Comment: The condition that $f''(x_0) = 0 $ is necessary but not sufficient to guarantee the existence of an inflection in $x_0$, because the second derivative may not change sign around $x_0$: this happens if the function has at the point a contact "superior to the second order" with its own tangent line. I did not fully understand your justification for the answer **E** when you write "Additionally...etc....

Comment: Okay, even if part of my explanation seems to be wrong you can prove that **E** is false by giving a counter-example. I guess it won't be so hard to find one.